# Why Reactjs has to reuse code in HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

All I want is to run a piece of javascript code to query back-end GraphQL server. Why do I have to wrap my query in a HOC component? Like it says in [this document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html#creating-client).

```
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

    const ExchangeRates = () => (
      <Query
        query={gql`
          {
            rates(currency: "USD") {
              currency
              rate
            }
          }
        `}
      >
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

          return data.rates.map(({ currency, rate }) => (
            <div key={currency}>
              <p>{`${currency}: ${rate}`}</p>
            </div>
          ));
        }}
      </Query>
    );
```

It looks like a very clumsy awkward solution? Why it has to be this way? Does it make things easier or more difficult? What is the philosophy behind it?

**Update:**

One thing trouble a lot is: I just want to make an API call, which is not visible, why do I have to render a  tag inside render() function? API call are not supposed to be visible at all. This twist make me feel this whole HOC thing is a hack, bogus. What do you think?

Comment: Here is their rationalization: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/why-apollo.html.

Comment: It's definitely less awkward than handling the entire request lifecycle. The Query component is abstracting all state handling and other request-related functionality from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use `Render Prop Pattern` because of it's highly declarative nature as outlined [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/why-apollo.html#declarative-data)

> This encapsulation makes composing your Query components with your presentational components a breeze

Now about the `Render Prop` itself, as per official react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

> The term “render prop” refers to a simple technique for sharing code between React components using a prop whose value is a function.
>
> A component with a render prop takes a function that returns a React element and calls it instead of implementing its own render logic.

As described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#use-render-props-for-cross-cutting-concerns) this technique is React's favoured way of handling cross-cutting concerns.

> Components are the primary unit of code reuse in React, but it’s not a always obvious how to share the state or behavior that one component encapsulates to other components that need that same state.

So with `render prop` you put out only the public outcome of your encapsulated state that you want to share with other components.

`render prop` is not `HoC`, but is an alternative to it, that was recently embraced by the react team itself.

Comment: One thing trouble a lot is: I just want to make an API call, which is not visible, why do I have to render a <Query> tag inside render() function? API call are not supposed to be visible at all. This twist make me feel this whole HOC thing is a hack, bogus.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu you don't have to, you can use HoC like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/406125pk80) to inject your request logic, instead of a render prop with a `<Query />`. But eventually you are going to put the results of your data manipulations into render. You can choose to mix it all under one component, but you can also separate it into its own one. So Query component is a natural consequence of defining a declarative interface for that. You can also read about the benefits of query component pattern [here](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-components-with-apollo-ec603188c157)